# Color Masking Effect in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

I am a game developer. I am trying to achieve background effect they used in game called Guns of Boom.

[image: UI example]

As seen on the screenshot, background image has some kind of masking effect which gave it a yellowish color and also made it a little bit faded. This effect reduced complexity of the background, which makes it easier to read UI elements.

I have checked various Photoshop tutorial, none of them gave me this effect. Does anybody know how to achieve such effect?

Comment: Hi berkc, Welcome to GD.SE! Can you tell us what you have tried? I don't think they did anything too specific. Looks like a solid color layer with the opacity turned down to like 50%.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I achieve colour overlay effect in PS?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/how-can-i-achieve-colour-overlay-effect-in-ps)

Comment: @AndrewH I tried color overlay in layers however they looked not as I wanted. I achieved the effect by the help of the answer below, thank you anyway for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new layer above the background layer, fill it with a light flesh colour, and reduce the opacity of the layer.

Here's an example

[image]

If you feel the effect is a bit too strong, set the layer blending mode to "Screen" as well.

[image]

Comment: I think this is the effect I am looking for. I tried blue version of it, it looks not as good as yellow mask but thank you for explaining in detail!

Comment: @berkc - feel free to experiment with different colours of fill.  This isn't an exact science, and the colour you choose may depend on the colours in the original background image.